# Filtering with vba Excel

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Hello everybody i would really appreciate your help with the following problem:

I have an Excel file that contains an hardware acquisition, with different sampling rate depending on the value (eg. some value acquiried at 100ms and others at 10ms in that case). So i have the first column with Time value (every cell is 10ms) and the following columns with the other acquiried values. Every column that corresponds to the 100ms acquisition frequency shows 10 blank cell after filled cell (while the 10ms ones are full). Now my question is:
What's the best whay to filter all the values and create a new table with only value took every 1s?
Thanks.
Here's a screenshot (simplified)

#### Image of the file

[image: Image of the file]

Comment: A more visual representation of the original data and the expected result would help!

Comment: Pivot table and grouping?

Comment: Is your time value a standard Excel time format or a count of milliseconds?

Comment: i've added a screedshot of the table. My time value are just numbers acquiried from an external hardware. let me now if is clear, thankyou!

Comment: About how many 1s time points do you have? I'm thinking if you actually use a filter, you might run into limits eventually.

Comment: Or advanced filter with a criteria for integer values

Comment: there are 1600-2000s, but consider that the raw time column have like 200000 cell

Comment: The limit I'm thinking of is number of distinct values you want to filter on <10000, so ~2000 sec should be OK.

Comment: An option is to create a helper column with a fomula that can categorise the data `=IF(ROUNDDOWN(A5,0) = A5,"DATASET","")`. Then you can easily filter "DATASET"

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a couple of loops like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopySeconds()
    Dim FirstRow, LastRow, inRow, inCol, outRow, outCol, colShift As Variant
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    FirstRow = 4
    outRow = FirstRow
    colShift = 10
    For inRow = FirstRow To LastRow
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(inRow, 1)) And Int(Cells(inRow, 1)) = Cells(inRow, 1) Then
        For inCol = 1 To 4
        outCol = inCol + colShift
        Cells(outRow, outCol) = Cells(inRow, inCol)
        Next inCol
        outRow = outRow + 1
    End If
    Next inRow

End Sub
```